# Different Tkinter Canvases, with an image background, switch with a quick white flash

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to make a game using tkinter GUI. My aim is to make different Canvas, with same or different images as a background, for different menus/screens.
But I have noticed that when I switch between different menus (canvases), there is a quick white flash during the switching which is undesirable. As far as I know, this is because when I "pack_forget" the previous canvas and pack the new one, the is a small difference between the two events
But I want the switching to be smooth because such a flickering doesn't look good in a game.
I have attached a code below. The code is a bit long. Actually I tried to reduce it as much as I could. So the code below is the minimum required code to check the problem.

This is what you should do:

1. Run the program and click "New Game".
2. Then click the 'Back' arrow shown at the bottom of the window.
3. If you are unable to notice the flickering (or you may say "A quick white flash"), then keep repeating step 1 and 2.

The Image for the canvas background is attached here:
[Image for Canvas background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfha2.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from functools import partial

class DiceGame(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DiceGame, self).__init__()

        self.title("Dice Cricket")
        self.geometry('980x660+200-60')
        self.state('zoomed')

        self.font1 = ('Algerian', 95, 'bold')
        self.font2 = ('Comic Sans MS', 50, 'bold')
        self.font3 = ('Comic Sans MS', 40, 'bold')
        self.font4 = ('Comic Sans MS', 30, 'bold')
        self.font5 = ('Comic Sans MS', 25, 'bold')
        self.bgcolor = '#366649'

        self.background1 = PhotoImage(file = 'dicepic9.png')
        self.back_image = PhotoImage(file = "back arrow.png").subsample(7,7)
        self.MainMenu()
        self.Actice_Window = "MainMenu"

    def gameTitle(self, root):
        title_Label = Label(root,
                        text = "Dice Cricket",
                        font = self.font1,
                        bg = self.bgcolor,
                        fg = 'yellow')
        title_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 15, ipadx = 100)
    
    def backbutton(self, root):
        self.back_Label = Label(root,
                            text = "Back",
                            font = self.font5,
                            fg = "Yellow",
                            bg = self.bgcolor,
                            image = self.back_image,
                            compound = LEFT)

        return self.back_Label

    def MainMenu(self):
        self.MainMenu_Canvas = Canvas(self, bg = self.bgcolor, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
        self.MainMenu_Canvas.create_image(2, 2, anchor = NW, image = self.background1)
    
        self.gameTitle(self.MainMenu_Canvas)

        self.MainMenu_Frame = Frame(self.MainMenu_Canvas)
        self.MainMenu_Frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10, ipadx = 20)

        self.MainMenu_Label = Label(self.MainMenu_Frame,
                        text = "Main Menu",
                        font = self.font2,
                        bg = self.bgcolor,
                        fg = 'orange')
        self.MainMenu_Label.pack(fill = X, pady = (0,0))

        self.Options_Frame = Frame(self.MainMenu_Frame, bg = 'gray10', bd = 4, relief = GROOVE)
        self.Options_Frame.pack(fill = X, ipady = 5, ipadx = 60)
        label1 = Label(self.Options_Frame, text = "New Game", font = self.font4, fg = "light green", bg = "gray10")
        label1.pack()
        label1.bind('<Button-1>', self.NewGame_Menu)

    def NewGame_Menu(self, event):
        self.Actice_Window = "NewGame Menu"
        self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack_forget()

        self.NewGameMenu_Canvas = Canvas(self, bg = self.bgcolor, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
        self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = self.background1)

        self.gameTitle(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas)

        self.NewGame_Frame = Frame(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas, bg = self.bgcolor)
        self.NewGame_Frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10)

        self.selection_Label = Label(self.NewGame_Frame, text = "Select Game Type", font = self.font3, fg = "Silver", bg = self.bgcolor)
        self.selection_Label.pack()

        self.Matchtype_Frame = Frame(self.NewGame_Frame, bg = 'gray10', bd = 4, relief = GROOVE)
        self.Matchtype_Frame.pack(ipadx = 60, ipady = 10, pady = 15)

        label2 = Label(self.Matchtype_Frame, text = "Quick Match", font = self.font4, fg = "light green", bg = "gray10")
        label2.pack()
    
        self.back1 = self.backbutton(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas)
        self.back1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 190, pady = 10)
        self.back1.bind('<Button-1>', self.Go_Back)

    def Go_Back(self, event):
        if self.Actice_Window == "NewGame Menu":
           self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.pack_forget()
           self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

dice = DiceGame()
dice.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you remove and recreate the canvases when switching canvas.

Below is a modified code based on yours:

- create canvases once
- use `place()` instead of `pack()` on canvases
- create a class method to raise a canvas to the front

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from functools import partial

class DiceGame(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DiceGame, self).__init__()

        self.title("Dice Cricket")
        self.geometry('980x660+200-60')
        self.state('zoomed')

        self.font1 = ('Algerian', 95, 'bold')
        self.font2 = ('Comic Sans MS', 50, 'bold')
        self.font3 = ('Comic Sans MS', 40, 'bold')
        self.font4 = ('Comic Sans MS', 30, 'bold')
        self.font5 = ('Comic Sans MS', 25, 'bold')
        self.font6 = ('Comic Sans MS', 15, 'bold')
        self.bgcolor = '#366649'

        self.background1 = PhotoImage(file = 'dicepic9.png')
        self.back_image = PhotoImage(file = "back arrow.png").subsample(7,7)

        self.MainMenu_Canvas = self.NewGameMenu_Canvas = None  ###
        self.MainMenu()

    def gameTitle(self, root):
        title_Label = Label(root,
                        text = "Dice Cricket",
                        font = self.font1,
                        bg = self.bgcolor,
                        fg = 'yellow')
        title_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 15, ipadx = 100)

    def createLabels(self, frame, LabelList, Labeltexts):
        for i in range(len(Labeltexts)):
            label = Label(frame, text = Labeltexts[i], font = self.font4, fg = 'light green', bg = 'gray10')
            label.pack(fill = X)
            LabelList.append(label)
    
        LabelList[0].pack_configure(pady = (10,0))
        self.selection(LabelList)

    def selection(self, LabelList):
        for label in LabelList:
            label.bind("<Enter>", partial(self.color_config, label, "maroon", "pink"))
            label.bind("<Leave>", partial(self.color_config, label, "light green", "grey10"))

    def color_config(self, widget, color1, color2, event):
        widget.configure(foreground = color1, bg = color2)

    def backbutton(self, root):
        self.back_Label = Label(root,
                            text = "Back",
                            font = self.font5,
                            fg = "Yellow",
                            bg = self.bgcolor,
                            image = self.back_image,
                            compound = LEFT)

        return self.back_Label

    ### raise a canvas to the front
    def raise_canvas(self, canvas):
        canvas.tk.call("raise", canvas)

    def MainMenu(self):
        self.Actice_Window = "MainMenu"  ### moved from __init__()
        if self.MainMenu_Canvas is None:
            self.MainMenu_Canvas = Canvas(self, bg = self.bgcolor, highlightthickness = 0)
            ###self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
            self.MainMenu_Canvas.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1) ###
            self.MainMenu_Canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = self.background1)
        
            self.gameTitle(self.MainMenu_Canvas)

            self.MainMenu_Frame = Frame(self.MainMenu_Canvas)
            self.MainMenu_Frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10, ipadx = 20)

            self.MainMenu_Label = Label(self.MainMenu_Frame,
                            text = "Main Menu",
                            font = self.font2,
                            bg = self.bgcolor,
                            fg = 'orange')
            self.MainMenu_Label.pack(fill = X, pady = (0,0))

            self.Options_Frame = Frame(self.MainMenu_Frame, bg = 'gray10', bd = 4, relief = GROOVE)
            self.Options_Frame.pack(fill = X, ipady = 5, ipadx = 60)

            mainLabels = []
            Labeltexts = ["New Game", "Load Game", "Hall of Fame", "Options", "Credits", "Exit Game"]
            self.createLabels(self.Options_Frame, mainLabels, Labeltexts)

            mainLabels[0].bind('<Button-1>', self.NewGame_Menu)

        self.raise_canvas(self.MainMenu_Canvas) ###


    def NewGame_Menu(self, event):
        self.Actice_Window = "NewGame Menu"
        ###self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack_forget()
        if self.NewGameMenu_Canvas is None:
            self.NewGameMenu_Canvas = Canvas(self, bg = self.bgcolor, highlightthickness = 0)
            ###self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
            self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1) ###
            self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = self.background1)

            self.gameTitle(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas)

            self.NewGame_Frame = Frame(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas, bg = self.bgcolor)
            self.NewGame_Frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10)

            self.selection_Label = Label(self.NewGame_Frame, text = "Select Game Type", font = self.font3, fg = "Silver", bg = self.bgcolor)
            self.selection_Label.pack()

            self.Matchtype_Frame = Frame(self.NewGame_Frame, bg = 'gray10', bd = 4, relief = GROOVE)
            self.Matchtype_Frame.pack(ipadx = 60, ipady = 10, pady = 15)

            newGameLabels = []
            newGameLabelsText = ["Quick Match", "Bilateral Series", "Tournament", "Practice"]
            self.createLabels(self.Matchtype_Frame, newGameLabels, newGameLabelsText)
        
            self.back1 = self.backbutton(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas)
            self.back1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 190, pady = 10)
            self.back1.bind('<Button-1>', self.Go_Back)

        self.raise_canvas(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas) ###

    def Go_Back(self, event):
        if self.Actice_Window == "NewGame Menu":
           ###self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.pack_forget()
           ###self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
           self.raise_canvas(self.MainMenu_Canvas) ###

dice = DiceGame()
dice.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you say they have to use `place` rather than `pack`? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: Using `place()` can overlap the canvases more easier than using `pack()`. `grid()` can be used as well.